# import java.util.*; import java.util.Scanner; I want the meaning of above statements, I am unaware about this statement in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.Scanner;
```

I want the meaning of above  statements, I am unaware about this statement in java.

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant because `import java.util.*;` imports everything inside util, including `Scanner`.